# How to implement keyboard shortcuts on websites

Tags: php, jquery, keyboard-shortcuts

Where should I begin if I want users to be able to use keyboard shortcuts on a site.
I'm currently using php and jquery to create site. How will I be able to add keyboard shortcuts aside from the usual point and click method. Links to site where I could begin will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a starter: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hotkeys

[Edit 1/14/14: Dead link.  See [the Github page instead](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys)]

Comment: I see that this topic is 8 years old. Is JavaScript and a jquery hotkeys plugin still the way to do this nowadays or is there some other java-free solutions? I am thinking of creating a webapp in Python/Flask and I would like to use the the webpage as a UI which would support keyboard shortcuts. I'd like to avoid JavaScript if I can.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at Mousetrap as well.

http://craig.is/killing/mice

It supports all types of key events as well as combinations and sequences.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [jQuery.hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) by John Resig, and it works pretty well with the latest jQuery. Have a look at the static page samples on the github page.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe also look into using the `accesskey` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin http://www.mattytemple.com/projects/shortcut-js/. It is simplistic in purpose and handles single combinations effectively.

If you need better implementation with more flexibility go for [Mousetrap Plugin](http://craig.is/killing/mice) as specified by @craig in the previous answer.

Comment: shortcut.js is no longer working or maintained by the developer. Another +1 from me for Mousetrap.