# How to excute keybord shortcuts using php in my webpage?

Tags: php, keyboard-shortcuts

How can i execute keyboard shortcuts using PHP in my webpage?.

> eg: ctrl+c , ctrl+v

Please help me.

Comment: possibly duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723334/how-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-on-websites.

Answer (score 5):

PHP is a server side language, meaning that it is executed on the server and never touches the client; only the output of the file reaches the client. In order to respond to keyboard events such as those, you're going to have to use javascript. You can use AJAX to request a PHP file when that event happens, but the bottom line is that you have to use javascript in order to find out when the user presses a key.

Answer (score 2):

Simple: you can't. PHP is a Serverside Language which is not capable of catching any Clientside input directly. You can do this with Javascript and send Ajax requests to your Script triggering functions, but this won't work with PHP only.

Look at [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593602/keyboard-shortcuts-with-jquery), as it has been asked before.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Javascript to achieve this. You can check this question to get more knowledge on it: [Javascript keyboard shortcuts for web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836596/javascript-keyboard-shortcuts-for-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

You cand do this with JQuery: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hotkeys .

Example: **$(document).bind('keydown', 'Ctrl+c', fn);**