# Php how to create keyboard shortcut for website

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I was wondering how I can add keyboard shortcut feature like twitter on my dynamic Php website? For example (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> - for comment).

Comment: Hi, please always remember to Google first. There is ample documentation for this on the web even when searching for `Php how to create keyboard shortcut for website`.

Comment: Check out this link.This might help u . :)


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723334/how-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-on-websites

Comment: Any keyboard shortcuts will be happening in the user's browser; hence, you need to care about javascript, not PHP. Anyway, this type of question is far too broad to be answered here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $(document).keydown(function(e){
    var keycode=e.keyCode;
    if (keycode == 27)
     {
                  $("#change").trigger('click');
     }
});
  $("#change").click(function() {
  //do what you need
  if($("#radio:checked").length==0)
    {
        alert("abc");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

take a look here http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keycodes.htm

example

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
                if (e.which === 13) {
                    $("#select").trigger('click');
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#saber').keypress(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.altKey && e.charCode==67){
        //do anything!
    }
});
```

NOTE: you can use `ctrlKey` or `shiftKey` instead of `altKey` and 67 is the charcode of 'c'character; another characters are listed in @sukhjit link.